# MS Access vba programmatically accessing and setting label properties

Tags: ms-access, vba, label

Is it possible to access labels programmatically with VBA. I'd like to create a number of labels using a for loop such as that shown below which would set all labels named "Label1" to "Label20" to visible

```
for a_counter = 1 to 20
Me.Label(a_counter).Visible = True
next a_counter
```

Is something such as the above possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to each of those label controls, "Label1" thru "Label20", by name from the form's Controls collection.

```
For a_counter = 1 To 20
    Me.Controls("Label" & a_counter).Visible = True
Next a_counter
```

Answer (score 1):

labels are a specific kind of controls in access forms. You should be able to write down some code like this:

```
function listLabels()
dim m_ctl as control

for each m_ctl in screen.activeForm.controls
    if m_ctl.type = ....   'please check the control types available!
        debug.print m_ctl.name
    end if
next m_ctl

end function
```

Be careful. I am not even sure of the control's properties (.type, .name) but you will easily find them in the help. Look for 'control' object.

Comment: `If ctl.ControlType = acLabel Then`, not ctl.Type

Comment: Thanks ... I guess I am missing some practise !

Comment: You could also set tags for those fields and search for those in the for loop (`m_ctl.tag`) instead of the control type.

Comment: I am not sure that 'tag' is a generic property of the 'control' object, even if it is available for most of the controls like these of the label type. So if I were you I would not go this way ....

Comment: I haven't had any problems with that approach. When I loop through controls I can use tag with everything (meaning textbox, combinationfield, listfield, labelfield). Even subform objects can have tags. It's pretty nice to use if you dynamically need to check fields for specific entries. I don't see any reason not to use that?